# Is the {% csrf_token %} CSRF protection tag still necessary in Django 1.2?

Tags: django, csrf

I am testing the CSRF protection on my site and I have noticed something unexpected.

I removed `{% csrf_token %}` from my form and the submission still works. I couldn't work out why. I then looked at the source and realised the token was still there right next to the `<form>` element. I changed the ID of the form to make sure it was definitely updating the source and it was but the hidden input is still there.

I am using Django 1.2. Is `{% csrf_token %}` still necessary?

Cheers

Rich

Comment: After more investigation it appears the {% csrf_token %} is always inserted if the form has method 'post' and not if it doesn't. Very clever Django. Auto protection.

Comment: post that as an answer and accept it (you might have to wait 24 hours before you can accept your own answer).

Answer (score 4):

After more investigation it appears the `{% csrf_token %}` is always inserted if the form has method `post` and not if it doesn't. Very clever auto protection from Django.

Comment: I believe this only takes place if you add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware` to your middleware classes. It is no longer recommended. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#legacy-method

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> In Django 1.1, the template tag did not exist. Instead, a post-processing middleware that re-wrote POST forms to include the CSRF token was used. If you are upgrading a site from version 1.1 or earlier, please read this section and the [Upgrading notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#upgrading-notes) below.
>
> http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#legacy-method