# "CSRF token missing or incorrect"

Tags: python, django, csrf

**EDIT SOLVED**: I feel like such a moron. I originally created two separate views: one for input and one for output. I had been handling all of the code here in the output view even though I rearranged my url and template to just reuse the input view... SORRY EVERYONE. It works fine now...

---

I'm running on localhost, and when I submit my form I'm getting a "CSRF token missing" error. I've read the documentation and some stackoverflows. I have already solved most of the common issues:

- I have the csrf token in my template (when loaded the template has inserted exactly this: `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">`)
- I am using render_to_response with `render_to_response('_template_',{_data_:'_data_'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
- I do have have RequestContext imported to my views
- I do have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in my settings.

Anyone have any idea what I could be missing?

Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>
```

Here is my view:

```
def view_workout(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        q = request.POST['q']
        if not request.POST.get('q', ''):
            errors.append('Please complete all required fields')
            return render_to_response('swimsets/view_workout.html',{
                'error': errors
            },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('swimsets/view_workout.html',{
                'query': q
            },context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:

        return render_to_response('swimsets/view_workout.html', {

    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: I just added it, deleted the views.pyc, restarted the localhost. still doesnt work.

Comment: I can't help but feel like the value of csrfmiddlewaretoken shouldn't be `""`. Can you try placing `{{ csrf_token }}` (notice double brackets, not percent signs) somewhere, and make sure it displays a real token?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing CsrfResponseMiddleware, based on an answer in related question [Is the {% csrf_token %} CSRF protection tag still necessary in Django 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323085/is-the-csrf-token-csrf-protection-tag-still-necessary-in-django-1-2)

Comment: i tried to add this to the middleware settings, 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',but then the server wouldnt even run...

Comment: Hmm, it seems that answer was quite old, and that middleware might not even exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You also may need to import csrf into your view:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
```

Comment: I just added it, deleted the views.pyc, restarted the localhost. still doesnt work

Comment: You could just use the decorator for the view: [CSRF Decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf) Otherwise I might try clearing out your browser data.

Comment: I tried clearing the .pyc, browser data, and I added an @csrf_protect above the view along with importing the csrf_protect and I'm still seeing the 403 error.